# Save value updates of a map in a new map as a value list of all previous values of the specific key's value

Tags: java

I am working on saving updates of a map in a new map where only the keys are the same as in the original map but the value of each key shows a list of all previous updates. My approach was:

1. receiving the update as a map from a server.
2. define a new map of the form key, value[]
3. Extract the values of the keys and add them to the value list

But the *put* and *get* methods do not seem to work here. Here is my code:

```
Map<String, String> map = DatatoJson.main(null);
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> new_map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    // check if a new map called new_map is empty in Java
    if (new_map.isEmpty()) {
        // include key and value of map in the new map "new_map"
        new_map.put(key, value);
    }

    // check if the key of the map is already in the new map
    if (new_map.containsKey(key)) {
        // get the key of new_map
        Map<String, List<String>> new_key = new_map.get(key);
        // check if new_key and key are the same
        if (new_key.equals(key)) {
            // if they are the same, then add the value of map to a value list in new_map corresponding to the key
            new_map.get(key).add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message will tell you exactly what the problem is. Your new_map is a Map of types `<String, Map<String>>` not `<String, String>` so the put method needs to watch it `new_map.put(key, inerMap);`, you'll need to construct the innerMap first, or change your new_map to be `<String, String>`

Comment: When I change the put || get method, I get the error that the getValues method is not working anymore. That is why I am confused

Comment: The problem you have with get is exactly the same, you are trying to mix types. Read the error message and it will tell you exactly that. if you get a value from a map of maps you need to assign it to a map variable, but if you get a value from a map of strings, then you need to assign it to a string variable.